# facebook integration in titanium

Tags: android, facebook, titanium, integration

I am developing an app that would open with the log in of facebook. So I want to know how to integrate facebook in my titanium app. Please suggest some sample codes and the steps ,how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This documentation link would help you understanding facebook integration with titanium

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Modules.Facebook

Thanks

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I would definitely look out this link.